# CSS width:100% not full screen

Tags: html, css

Alright so I am trying to create a top bar of my webpage like the one  at the top of this page and what my code looks like is this:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
</div>
<body>
```

and the css is

```
#header{
width:100%;
}
```

and when I look at in a browser it doesn't completely touch the sides, It's about 10px away. How do I fix the gap?

Answer (score 3):

you need to clear the default margin/padding that the browser sets on the body. Use:

```
body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E9SPX/2/)

Comment: padding is not neccessary!

Comment: @jingyinggong wouldn't that be `margin` that isn't necessary?

Comment: @jingyinggong Padding is necessary for some older Opera.

Comment: @m59 No, he's right (except for Opera), margin is the standard. Strange, I know.

Comment: @jingyinggong Nothing wrong with resetting both defaults. It's good practice.

Comment: That really makes no sense. I never thought about it before. I just use a CSS Reset..

Answer (score 0):

css should have this!

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
}
```

because default the body has some margin on it! you should remove them so the header can fill the body full!